# Qt compile error when use tslib with angstrom g++

Tags: qt, embedded, touchscreen, angstrom-linux

In the above scenario I am getting the following compile error. Can someone tell me why? I am using the following doc as my guide line

http://billforums.station51.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=15

```
ts_test.o: In function `main':
ts_test.c:(.text+0x1d8): undefined reference to `rpl_malloc'
fbutils.o: In function `open_framebuffer':
fbutils.c:(.text+0xa7c): undefined reference to `rpl_malloc'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [ts_test] Error 1
ts_harvest.o: In function `main':
ts_harvest.c:(.text+0x5d0): undefined reference to `rpl_malloc'
fbutils.o: In function `open_framebuffer':
fbutils.c:(.text+0xa7c): undefined reference to `rpl_malloc'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [ts_harvest] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/thwijeth/Downloads/tslib-1.0/tests'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/thwijeth/Downloads/tslib-1.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
ts_test.o: In function `main':
ts_test.c:(.text+0x1d8): undefined reference to `rpl_malloc'
fbutils.o: In function `open_framebuffer':
fbutils.c:(.text+0xa7c): undefined reference to `rpl_malloc'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [ts_test] Error 1
ts_harvest.o: In function `main':
ts_harvest.c:(.text+0x5d0): undefined reference to `rpl_malloc'
fbutils.o: In function `open_framebuffer':
fbutils.c:(.text+0xa7c): undefined reference to `rpl_malloc'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [ts_harvest] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/thwijeth/Downloads/tslib-1.0/tests'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/thwijeth/Downloads/tslib-1.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [simple Google search on "rpl_malloc"](https://www.google.com/search?q=rpl_malloc) finds many references to this issue, with suggestions for solutions.  The problem is that the Autoconf configure script is having trouble finding `malloc` for some reason, and tries to fall back to `rpl_malloc`.  There are a couple of suggestions to work around this:

1.) Define the `ac_cv_func_malloc_0_nonnull=yes` environment variable before you run `configure`, for instance by running configure (assuming a bash shell) as:

```
ac_cv_func_malloc_0_nonnull=yes ./configure <your configure options>
```

or

2.) Manually change the configure script to comment out the `rpl_malloc problem AC_FUNC_MALLOC` line by prefixing it with a `#`.

(Reference: [this blog post, among others](http://rickfoosusa.blogspot.com/2011/11/howto-fix-undefined-reference-to.html))